# Ren'Py - If Elif Dialogue Statement

Tags: renpy

My code:

```
if $ nice_dec4 = true:
    a "Last night, was fantastic, I.."
    
    a "Needed it."
elif $ mean_dec4 = true:
    a "Hey.."

    a "I was wondering if.."

    a "Nevermind."

    b "NO!"

    b "Could I.. stay over?"

    show sloane tired school

    a "Why would you lie to me..?"

    a "Why do you hit the mouse button like this isn't my life."

    a "Why don't you care.. anymore?"

    a "Come back soon,"

    a "{b}{i}Darling."
```

The traceback is as follows:

```
[code]
I'm sorry, but an uncaught exception occurred.

While running game code:
  File "game/script.rpy", line 712, in script
    if $ nice_dec4 = true:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (script.rpy, line 712)

-- Full Traceback ------------------------------------------------------------

Full traceback:
  File "game/script.rpy", line 712, in script
    if $ nice_dec4 = true:
  File "/Users/NAME/Desktop/renpy-8.0.1-sdk/renpy/ast.py", line 2115, in execute
    if renpy.python.py_eval(condition):
  File "/Users/NAME/Desktop/renpy-8.0.1-sdk/renpy/python.py", line 1081, in py_eval
    code = py_compile(code, 'eval')
  File "/Users/NAME/Desktop/renpy-8.0.1-sdk/renpy/python.py", line 1018, in py_compile
    raise e
  File "/Users/NAME/Desktop/renpy-8.0.1-sdk/renpy/python.py", line 970, in py_compile
    raise orig_e
  File "/Users/NAME/Desktop/renpy-8.0.1-sdk/renpy/python.py", line 963, in py_compile
    tree = compile(source, filename, py_mode, ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST | flags, 1)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (script.rpy, line 712)

macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit x86_64
Ren'Py 8.0.2.22081402
Me And Sloane 1.2
Sun Dec  4 15:33:04 2022
[/code]
```

I expected the code to change based on a decision I made the player make earlier, all I got was this error.

IGNORE-----------------------------------------------------------------

"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details":
mabklwglabd,jagdwlvgkulygwdvg agwlgd. w gdwilyavjkdfwvakuwdmvawwhmgwa,fywdjgcwfuwgcmhv aw,vw j,   dwa dfldf,vdwm kw amvwdjawf wdlva;hwjha.,mww

Answer (score 0):

When you use an if/elif operator in Ren'Py, you don't need to use the $ symbol.

```
if nice_dec4 = true:
    a "Last night, was fantastic, I.."
    a "Needed it."

elif mean_dec4 = true:
    a "Hey.."
    a "I was wondering if.."
```

$ symbol is used to define variables. For example, $ var1 = True